# How to use imagepicker library to pick video from gallery

Tags: flutter, dart, imagepicker

I am using image_picker: ^0.6.7+22, when I use the library to select a video from gallery only photos appear. There  is no way to select a  video from my gallery.

```
 final video = await picker.getVideo(source: ImageSource.gallery);
```

Comment: maybe the window which opens up on this code is on recent items. Try to use the drawer to change the location.

Comment: Are you using a real device to test, and did you have any video on it?

Comment: I used my iPhone, yes and it had many videos on it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to display and play a video we need to depend on third party because Flutter doesn’t support video playback by default
So for displaying videos You have to use video_player plugin
Add this dependency in pubspec.yaml
video_player: ^0.11.1+2

this is a function for playing a video in Flutter:

```
_pickVideo() async {
    PickedFile pickedFile = await picker.getVideo(source: ImageSource.gallery);
     _video = File(pickedFile.path); 
    _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.file(_video)..initialize().then((_) {
      setState(() { });
      _videoPlayerController.play();
    });
}
```

Comment: I dont think you grasped my question.
I know how to display a video, its just that when I open the gallery, no videos are shown.